# QEMU QMP How to find device to use drive_backup?

Tags: backup, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I would like to use backup_drive command to copy disks and their snapshot in one image.

Unfortunately, each time i use the command :

```
virsh qemu-monitor-command VM_NAME --hmp drive_backup device=drive-ide0-0-0 sync=full target=/mnt/mig-kvm/test_sync_snap.qcow2
```

But i get this error :

```
Device 'device=ide0-0-0' not found
```

I tried devices i found with "domblklist" and "execute query-block"

Someone can give me an example to know whats exactly the "device" i need to put in the backup_drive command ?

i already check  this post without success :
[QEMU cannot find device nor node_name](https://serverfault.com/questions/795804/qemu-cannot-find-device-nor-node-name)

Thanks !

Best regards,
N.B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `info block` monitor command will show you the block devices connected to the guest.

```
[root@makrura ~]# virsh qemu-monitor-command hyperv-server-2016 --hmp "info block"
drive-scsi0-0-0-0 (#block118): /var/lib/libvirt/images/hyperv-server-2016.qcow2 (qcow2)
    Attached to:      scsi0-0-0-0
    Cache mode:       writeback

drive-sata0-0-1 (#block396): /var/lib/libvirt/isos/14393.0.160916-1106.RS1_REFRESH_SERVERHYPERCORE_OEM_X64FRE_EN-US.ISO (raw, read-only)
    Attached to:      sata0-0-1
    Removable device: not locked, tray closed
    Cache mode:       writeback

drive-sata0-0-2 (#block542): /usr/share/virtio-win/virtio-win-0.1.141.iso (raw, read-only)
    Attached to:      sata0-0-2
    Removable device: not locked, tray closed
    Cache mode:       writeback
```

Here, the disk device name is `drive-scsi0-0-0-0`. (The other block devices are virtual CDROM devices.) But what `drive_backup` expects is the node_name, which appears in parentheses, i.e. `#block118`.

It also appears you don't have the syntax quite correct. From the help:

```
drive_backup [-n] [-f] [-c] device target [format] -- initiates a point-in-time
            copy for a device. The device's contents are
            copied to the new image file, excluding data that
            is written after the command is started.
            The -n flag requests QEMU to reuse the image found
            in new-image-file, instead of recreating it from scratch.
            The -f flag requests QEMU to copy the whole disk,
            so that the result does not need a backing file.
            The -c flag requests QEMU to compress backup data
            (if the target format supports it).
```

So you would do something like:

```
[root@makrura ~]# virsh qemu-monitor-command hyperv-server-2016 --hmp "drive_backup -f #block118 /tmp/test.qcow2 qcow2"


[root@makrura ~]# ls -l /tmp/test.qcow2 
-rw-r--r--. 1 qemu qemu 982712320 Aug  7 11:19 /tmp/test.qcow2
```

Comment: Hi Michael,

Thanks a lot for the answer, "info block" is more readable than the "query block" 
command.
But i get the same device :

      root@ubuntukvm05:/# virsh qemu-monitor-command VM_NAME --hmp "info block"
drive-ide0-0-0 (#block12515):

Comment: @PoPNicoW I played around with it some more. Please see the edited answer.

Comment: your explanation is perfectly clear, that help me a lot in my understanding of qmp command. but i'm till getting the error device not found with #block[number]...with two different guest..but works with the device "drive-ide0-0-0" for one...so i guess my first vm is corrupted. Just one more question, does it mean we can't use same argument with JSON and with --hmp like sync (full, top, none...)?

Comment: All is good with this command :

virsh qemu-monitor-command NAME-VM \ '{"execute":"drive-backup", "arguments": {"device": "drive-virtio-disk0", "sync": "full", "target": "/mnt/backupkvm/testbackupfull.qcow2" }}'
{"return":{},"id":"libvirt-99"}